# Many queries running in parallel. does commit on one query affect every other query?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

Many queries running in parallel. does commit on one query affect every other query ?

```
q1 - updates tables (t1) ---- commit (t3)
q2 - updates tables (t2) (no commit executed) -- still executing some other (t5)
```

does q1 commit affect q2. can i roll back changes made at (t2) time

Comment: Are these the same connection or different connections?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by affecting other transactions? Each transaction can be committed and rolled back separately. Depending on isolation level setting, a transaction may not even see the changes committed by an other transaction.

Comment: The rows updated inside q2 will be locked from the time they are updated until the commit, so q1 cannot update them. the rollback will be go back to that point.

Comment: @Barmar different connections
q1 updates some records and; q2 also updates come records

Comment: If they're separate connections, then they're independent transactions. Committing one transaction has no effect on other transactions.